# Three.js - Angle between Planes

Tags: javascript, three.js, angle, plane

I'm working on an application using three.js and I'm wondering how could I compute the angle(let' call it α) between two plane geometries(take a look at the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvXTA.png))

Comment: Find the angle between their normals in world coordinates? `n1.angleTo(n2)`

Comment: You mean the normals of their position vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of 2 planes (using PlaneHelper to visualize the planes) and the calculation for the angle between them.

You can get the `normal` of the planes and calculate the angle between the normals using `normal1.angleTo(normal2)`.

If you wanted to know the angle of the planes themselves; then the 2 planes, and the 2 normals form a square.  You know the normals come out at 90 degrees from the planes, and you know the angle between normals.

So the angle between planes will be `360 - (normal_angle + 180)`.

NOTE: If you are using `PlaneGeometry` you could create your `Plane` by using 3 points from your `PlaneGeometry` like this:

```
const vertices = plane.geometry.attributes.position.array;
const plane1 = new THREE.Plane();
plane1.setFromCoplanarPoints(
     new THREE.Vector3(vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[2]), 
     new THREE.Vector3(vertices[3], vertices[4], vertices[5]), 
     new THREE.Vector3(vertices[6], vertices[7], vertices[8])
);
```

```js
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            camera.position.z = 5;
      
      const plane1= new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 0.2 ), 2 );
const helper = new THREE.PlaneHelper( plane1, 6, 0xffff00 );
scene.add( helper );

      const plane2= new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( -0.5, 0.2, 0.2 ), 2 );
const helper2 = new THREE.PlaneHelper( plane2, 6, 0xff00 );
scene.add( helper2 );

      const normal_angle_radians = plane1.normal.angleTo(plane2.normal);
      
      const normal_angle_degress = radians_to_degrees(normal_angle_radians);
      
      const angle_between_planes = 360 - normal_angle_degress - 180;
      
      alert('The degrees angle between planes is: '+ angle_between_planes);



            const animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };
      
      function radians_to_degrees(radians)
{
  var pi = Math.PI;
  return radians * (180/pi);
}

            animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. The problem is that I'm working with plane geometries: how can I calculate the normal of a plane geometry? Or, alternatively, how can I convert a plane geometry(type: planeGeometry) to a plane(type: Plane)?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how it can work with PlaneGeometry